# Clustering of binary/nominal variables in one sample

Tags: clustering, factor-analysis, binary-data, categorical-data

Assume that a medical school classifies its active, full-time students according to their free time activities. By distributing simple questionnaires individuals have to answer whether or not they're keen on a particular habit (Yes/No) and the following comprises only a small piece of the final results;

[image]

I've been searching (rather unsuccessfully) for a way to group positive responses that appear to have a statistically significant correlation eg. students who attend business workshops are also likely to be interested in programming too. That might extend to three or four variables depending on the factors provided by the method. Factor analysis rings some bells, but the data are purely nominal and there's no outcome in the form of a scale or ordinal variable. Any ideas ?

So far I've produced the following resourceful conclusions in SPSS;

1. Frequency tables. Gives a general idea about the distribution.
2. Correlation matrix. Special attention is given to positive values that fall below the 0.05 (*) and 0.001 (**) levels of significance respectively.
3. Ordinal Regression. Provides a probability table, indicating the chances of two positive responses in two different variables to be found the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try latent class analysis (LCA), though I'm not sure if SPSS can do it.

LCA assumes that there are underlying (latent) classes, and all individuals belong to one of them. In short, using LCA you can identify clusters of students, grouped by free time activities. For example, you might find that there is one group that is mainly interested in business and programming, another group that is mainly interested in programming and painting, a third group that is interested in movies, and all groups are interested in traveling.

LCA is useful if you believe there are certain latent groups and you want to measure how prevalent they are, or if you simply want to characterize the groups. It is also useful as a data reduction tool. E.g. you might want to predict academic performance based on group affinity rather than on the free time activity variables themselves, because otherwise you might need to include interaction terms and you would need to estimate lots of parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'll probably have to look somewhere else rather than SPSS to do it.

Comment: You could try the poLCA package in R, quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not use clustering**.

You are looking for **association rules** instead. Give Apriori a try, it is designed exactly for the task of finding rules of the kind $$A, B, C \rightarrow D$$

Comment: I've done my research and this is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm just surprised that most papers that I've came across prefer hierarchical clustering for similar issues. I am also intersted in producing groups of students (non-overlapping) based on the association. What would you suggest on that ?

Comment: Would you mind explaining this a bit in layman's terms?